# Find and retrieve keyed value from anywhere in JSON string

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I'm retrieving JSON which may vary in content items and want to find values associated with particular keys, e.g. in this case "geo_latitude" and "geo_longitude". For clarity, I'm only including those two items in this JSON sample. (It's typically much longer and in no particular order).

```
[
  {
    "id": 524616,
    "key": "geo_latitude",
    "value": "36.1069652"
  },
  {
    "id": 524617,
    "key": "geo_longitude",
    "value": "-112.1129972"
  }
]
```

This was the best I was able to come up with to parse the JSON. Is there a better way?

```
var metadataObj = JArray.Parse(postMetadataJsonStr);

var latContainer = metadataObj.Descendants()
    .OfType<JObject>()
    .Where(x => x["key"] != null &&
                x["key"].Value<string>() == "geo_latitude").Select(y => y["value"]);

var latTokenJValue = latContainer.FirstOrDefault();
if (latTokenJValue == null) return;
var latitude = latTokenJValue.ToString();
```

Comment: You could try using [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm).  It supports [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) query syntax.

Comment: Also, you can use an [explicit cast to string](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) on `JToken` and avoid the `null` check: `.Where(x => (string)x["key"] == "geo_latitude")`, which looks a little simpler.

Comment: @dbc Using SelectTokens, I'm able to come up with var latitude = metadataObj.SelectToken("$[?(@.key == 'geo_latitude')].value").ToString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert your json to a dictionary

```
var metadataObj = JArray.Parse(postMetadataJsonStr);
var dict = metadataObj.ToDictionary(x => (string)x["key"], x => (double)x["value"]);

Console.WriteLine(dict["geo_latitude"]);
```

Comment: Incidentally (and I know I didn't include this in my sample data) I had to treat the dictionary values as strings. Most of the rest of the data is textual. Just meant an additional conversion to double at the appropriate time.

Comment: @Stonetip then replace `(double)` in answer with `(string)`